# Can I make a "Game" in Java and use the source code on Android with out changing?

Tags: java, android

Just a really quick question and thank you ahead of time for any one who reads|| reply's.

My Question is if I make a game or any type of application within Java(Eclipse),
Can I then take that source code and import it into a program like Android Studio, or use the Sdk within Eclipse for Android. And it will work fine on android based devices with no changes to the code?

~Thank you

Comment: Short answer..No. You will need to code to the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you might reuse a big part of code.